# How to check whether the check box is checked or not capybara Rspec

Tags: html, rspec, capybara

CHECK

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="yes_1212" class="check_uncheck" type="checkbox" value="true" name="yes" checked="checked">
    <label></label>
    </div>
```

UNCHECK

```
 <div class="checkbox ">
    <input id="allow__100" class="check_uncheck" type="checkbox" value="false" name="Allow">
    <label></label>
    </div>
```

how to check whether the check box is checked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="allow__100" class="check_uncheck" type="checkbox" value="false" name="Allow">
```

For input type checkbox

```
 page.find(:css,
                      "input#allow__100", visible: false
                    ).should_not be_checked
```

Comment: Pls check the below answer, that might tell you the right code to use for returning the value

Comment: Attention: This solution won't wait until the field is really checked. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41648136/364590

Answer (score 45):

There are multiple ways depending on exactly what you're trying to do - if you've already found the element and just want to know whether or not it's checked you can do something like

```
element = find('#yes_1212')
...
element.checked?
```

If you're trying to assert that the box is on the page and is checked/unchecked you could do

```
expect(page).to have_field('yes_1212', checked: true) # checked: false or unchecked: true for not checked
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_checked_field('yes_1212')  # or have_unchecked_field
```

If you want a boolean response and don't already have a reference to the element

```
page.has_field?('allow__100', unchecked: true)
page.has_unchecked_field?('allow_100')
```

In all cases if the input element is actually non-visible for styling reasons you can pass `visible: false`

Comment: I want to only check whether the filed is checked

Comment: @jerrytom then `checked?` or `has_field?` style is what you want

Answer (score 8):

'expect' syntax:

```
expect(page.find("input#yes_1212")).to be_checked

expect(page.find("input#yes_1212")).not_to be_checked
```

Comment: Attention: This solution won't wait until the field is really checked.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting the checkbox's status.
In the code you can see `find(locator_strategy, locator_xpath` here `locator_strategy` is if you are searching the locator by `:xpath` or `:css` and the second parameter is `locator_xpath` which is locator written in the way the first parameter is defined.

So here first way is either you can assign the element you have found and then using `element.checked?` to get the status of checkbox, whether its checked or not checked. This would return either **true** or **false**

```
def method_name
 element = find(locator strategy, locator_xpath)
 return element.checked?
end
```

or, second way, which I feel is better way to proceed and consumes less line of codes.

```
def method_name
 return find(locator strategy, locator_xpath).checked?
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thanks for showing the art of writing the answers in a way to let help others learn the concept in better way.